# Django CBV with uuid as parameter

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm new to Django and while I'm okay with FBVs, I'm trying to learn CBVs and I'm stuck at one point. I have this in urls.py:

```
uuid='\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w'

url(r'^someroute/$', MyView.as_view(), name="my_list_view"),
url(r'^someroute/(?P<uuid>%s)/$' % uuid, MyDetailView.as_view(), name="my_detail_view"),
```

The first one works just fine. It extends ListView. The second one extends DetailView and I get this error when I click on a properly rendered link with uuid:

```
Generic detail view MyDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

I browsed the net for a solution, encountered several of them, but nothing seemed to solve my issue.
This is MyDetailView (so far I just want it to render an empty template, then I'll continue):

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'someroute/my_detail.html'
    slug_filed = 'uuid' #here I tried several variations, but nothing
```

Instead of slug_field, I also tried:

```
pk_url_kwarg = 'uuid'
```

But then I get this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1c149e4a-8629-464f-9c62-2742f82e6d96'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    slug_url_kwarg = 'uuid'
    slug_field = 'uuid'

    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'someroute/my_detail.html'
```

Comment: I just tried it and got this: Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field. Choices are: (here are all the fields in this class, including uuid)

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error :( The code has updated (I added a breakpoint to make sure), but the error is the same. I event followed the same structure as you did in your answer.

Comment: In the url you create for "MyDetailView" you have to use "uuid" as the regex parameter name, e.g. "url('^(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/$', MyDetailView.as_view())"

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is [`slug_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) (not slug_filed).